# understanding sed, awk and curl interaction extracting ssh URL information from github page

Tags: bash, awk, xargs

I needed to pull every public repo in a user's GitHub account. To do this I got the API output of https://api.github.com/users/SOMEUSER/repos

This is what I came up with. To extract the ssh_url line from the file I:

```
sed -n '/ssh_url/p' SOMEFILE
```

Now I am left with the ssh url to the repo but there are quotes around it. Now I came up with:

```
awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Then I put it all together:

```
curl https://api.github.com/users/SOMEUSER/repos | sed -n '/ssh_url/p' | awk -F\" '{print $(NF-1)}' | xargs -n1 git clone
```

Now I got it to work, that's good and great. Why does it work?

Comment: The URL doesn't work (no useful content).

Comment: Its not supposed to work I'm just giving it as an example.

Comment: This works because you got lucky. Using `sed` & `awk` to parse json, is almost as smart as parsing HTML with `sed` & `awk`.

Comment: I see that from the other answer below. I didn't know that.

Comment: I see that from the other answer below. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/ssh_url/p'
```

prints all lines which contain the string `ssh_url`. That's not what `sed` is usually used for. This would be done with `grep` (and with `awk` being used, too, `awk` can do that itself):

```
grep ssh_url

awk -F\" '/ssh_url/ {print $(NF-1)}'
```

`-F\"` means that `awk` separates the content of a line at `"` chars. `NF` is the number of fields i.e. there are `NF-1` `"` chars in that line. `print $(NF-1)` prints the last but one field. If the line is `foo"bar"baz` then `bar` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Since this command returns a JSON string, I'd use a JSON parser, [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq)

```
url="https://api.github.com/users/USER/repos"
curl -s "$url" | jq '.[]|.ssh_url' | tr -d '"'
```

That jq script means, for each element of the array, give me the value of the "ssh_url" member. The use tr to delete double quotes.

Comment: Ok I didn't not know that. That would have been much easier I believe. My solution did work which saved me from doing it by hand like I thought I had to.